# How to remove an element from in a jlist?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

How can I properly remove an element/item in a jlist? Because I always run into this error.
I cannot find any solution from google.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:734)
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:477)
at javax.swing.DefaultListModel.getElementAt(DefaultListModel.java:89)
```

Model: `DefaultListModel CartModel = new DefaultListModel();`

`Cart.setModel(CartModel);`

JList: `private javax.swing.JList Cart;`

Nevermind the StringSearch method.

My code:

```
private void removeFromCartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                               
   if(!CartModel.isEmpty()) {
       String selectedText = (String)CartModel.getElementAt(Cart.getSelectedIndex());
       StringSearch(selectedText,2);
       CartModel.removeElementAt(Cart.getSelectedIndex());
   }
}
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hadcoded value for JList in local variable

Comment: The removing is not the problem as you may have noticed then debugging correctly - the finding of the object crashes: `getElementAt`

Comment: As far as I know, `-1` is returned when no elements are selected.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is really easy t solve by reading the API and won't likely help future visitors. It surely has been asked before.

Comment: `I cannot find any solution from google.` - Did you read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)? It has a working example that shows you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`getSelectedIndex()` returns `-1` when no element is selected on JList.
Try to check if you have element selected, and then process with your logic.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedIndex())